# Angularjs2 - preload server configuration before the application starts

Tags: angular

I am working with Angular2 RC5. I would like to be able to load my server IP address and some other configuration parameters before my app boots up. How can I do this in the latest RC5?

I have seen other articles, but they are not helpful:

1. [How to preload a config file in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992671/how-to-preload-a-config-file-in-angular2): The answer provided here is specific to webpack. I am using systemjs.
2. https://medium.com/@hasan.hameed/reading-configuration-files-in-angular-2-9d18b7a6aa4#.m8lontnas: This is for the older version of Angular2. Some of the classes used are deprecated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

I tried to use the APP_INITIALIZER as follows in my app.module.ts:

```ts
    import { NgModule, provide, APP_INITIALIZER }       from "@angular/core";
    import { ConfigService } from "./shared/services/config.service";
    @NgModule({
        declarations: [AppComponent],
        imports: [BrowserModule,
            routes,
            FormsModule,
            HttpModule],
        providers: [AuthService,
            Title,
            appRoutingProviders,
            ConfigService],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent
            , provide(APP_INITIALIZER,
                {
                    useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => () => config.load(),
                    deps: [ConfigService], multi: true
                })]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

This is my config.service.ts file:

```ts
    import { Config } from "../model/config";

    export class ConfigService {
        constructor() {
        }

        load(): Promise<Config> {
            let config: Config = new Config("localhost", "5050");
            return Promise.resolve(config);
        }
    }
```

Note that I will eventually re-write load to actually read a property or some such file to load configuration.

This is what config.ts looks like:

```ts
export class Config {

    constructor(
        private machine: string,
        private port: string
    ) {
    }

    private base_url: string = "http://" + this.machine +
    this.port + "/";

    public loginURL: string = this.base_url + "login";
}
```

I am getting a compile error

```ts
public/app/app.module.ts(27,11): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ declarations: (typeof AppComponent ...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModuleMetadataType'.
  Types of property 'bootstrap' are incompatible.
    Type '(typeof AppComponent | Provider)[]' is not assignable to type '(Type | any[])[]'.
      Type 'typeof AppComponent | Provider' is not assignable to type 'Type | any[]'.
        Type 'Provider' is not assignable to type 'Type | any[]'.
          Type 'Provider' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
            Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'Provider'.
```

**Edit 2**

I move on to the next step. Update ConfigService to read a json file using http.get. Now I get an error. Here are the updated files:

```ts
export class ConfigService {
    private config: Config;
        constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    load(): Promise<Config> {
            this.http.get("/blah/config.json")
                 .map(res => res.json())
                 .subscribe((env_data) => {
                     console.log(env_data);
                  });
        this.config = new Config("localhost", "5050");
        return Promise.resolve(this.config);
    }

    getConfig(): Config {
        return this.config;
    }
}
```

Here is the providers section in NgModule class

```ts
    providers: [AuthService,
    Title,
    appRoutingProviders,
    ConfigService,
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => () => config.load(),
        deps: [ConfigService, Http],
        multi: true
    }],
```

Note that in RC6 I am not able to import HTTP_PROVIDERS since I get the error that these are not defined in the http module anymore. This is why I tried Http.

On runtime, I get following error

```ts
(index):27 Error: Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ConfigService: (?).(…)(anonymous function) @ (index):27
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:332
Zone.run @ zone.js:225(anonymous function) @ zone.js:591
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:365
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:265
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:497
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:437
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Provide this in your root module

```ts
{provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useValue: () => promise, multi: true}]}
```

where `() => promise` is some call that returns a Promise that resolves to the desired value.

See also [How to pass parameters rendered from backend to angular2 bootstrap method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method/37611614#37611614)

You can pass a service as dependency where you can store the result.

**update**

```ts
export function loadConfig(config: ConfigService) => () => config.load()

@NgModule({
        declarations: [AppComponent],
        imports: [BrowserModule,
            routes,
            FormsModule,
            HttpModule],
        providers: [AuthService,
            Title,
            appRoutingProviders,
            ConfigService,
            { provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
              useFactory: loadConfig,
              deps: [ConfigService], 
              multi: true }
        ],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

**update 2**

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/o7GohlMJ5nxgJtMEgKEP?p=preview)

Comment: I updated my answer. `provide()` is deprecated, I changed it to the new object literal form. In `@NgModule()` providers need to go to `providers: [...]`, the parameter after `bootstrap` was the way before `@NgModul()` existed.

Comment: The `ConfigService` does have the `@Injectable()` decorator?

Comment: I see, thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: Hello. I have provided `ConfigService` as you suggest in my root `NgModule` but when I debug in the browser `config.load()` it always returns undefinded.

Comment: Can't tell from this information. Seema to work for others. I'd suggest to create a new question with more details.

Comment: How do I inject my config in order to use the values in a component? I keep getting a "No provider for Config" error

Comment: I assume `providers: [...]` doesn't contain `Config`. If not please create a new question with your code. Hard to tell without seeing your code.

Comment: When using AOT, useFactory should not get a dynamic function, but rather exported function. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41636880/499839

Comment: @Mika thanks for the hint! AoT wasn't really a thing back then when I posted the answer. Updated my answer.

Comment: The problem is that promise inside config.load() method is resolved only after initialization. Do you have any idea how to manage this?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. Are you sure you're returning the `Promise` or `Observable` so that Angular can wait for it to complete?

Comment: No, I was returning Function instead Promise. Now when I changed returned value for a Promise<any> I'm getting error:

Comment: appInits[i] is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: appInits[i] is not a function

Comment: You can see plunker here https://plnkr.co/edit/P8iLISfjClIcwpAzsUsk?p=preview
Here is my stackoverflow question. You can answer there
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462636/how-to-make-a-request-before-angular-4-application-bootstrap?noredirect=1#comment77886373_45462636

Comment: You are using `useFactory`, not `useValue` like my example does. Your factory returns a `Promise`, my example returns a function that returns a Promise (or Observable) (`useValue: () => ...`

Comment: As I can see in updated part of your answer you use useFactory too.

Comment: I see. It might work as well, but it definitely needs to return a function, not a `Promise`

Comment: Okay, thanks. For now I've changed it to return a function (updated plunker), but I'm getting Cannot read property 'load' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined
Despite of the fact I added StartupService to providers array.

Comment: Do you have an idea what is going on - why my startupService is undefined? It seems deps was not injected, but why.

Comment: It would be much easier if you'd create a runnable Plunker that allows to reproduce. You only need to click the `new` button and then select `Angular` to get a prepared template.

Comment: Ok, here you go https://plnkr.co/edit/xaUydbigJ4oqHPK9wRpZ
It does not work because of the same reason it doesn't work in my application (same error)

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/o7GohlMJ5nxgJtMEgKEP?p=preview I think if you have `deps` then you need `useFactory` instead of `useValue`.

Comment: Yep, but even when I use useFactory - I cannot inject http into this service - it's undefined. Is there any way to do that from this level?

Comment: My updated Plunker shows that `http` is available. I also added a comment in the factory function why `http` wasn't available (`this.` doesn't work when the function is passed without `=>` or `.bind(startupService)`.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for that. And that example proves what I was talking about initially - that application does not wait for promise to be resolved with initialization. That is why I'm getting empty user object onInit AppComponent.
https://plnkr.co/edit/5vmpjixyhhX3y4xfnByZ?p=preview

Comment: Have you got any idea how to create solution where promise.resolve is before App component initialization? That's what is point of my question you marked as duplicate.

Comment: That was my mistake. I forgot the `return` inside `=> {...`

Comment: So you mean  return () => { return startupService.load() }; yep?

Comment: Yes, I updated the Plunker.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: Can you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66785098/passing-bearer-token-to-a-different-app-initializer-to-load-config-from-server-i . I would really really appreciate your guidance