# Create a server side configuration service for Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I’d like to create a configuration *something* that comes from the server side, depends on the current environment (development, staging, qa, production, etc.) and can be queried by my components.

Based on other answers here on SO I came up with a `Config` object that loads an `environment.json` file from the server, reads the `environment` key from that JSON data, and then loads the appropriate `config-<env>.json` file from the server into its private `_config` member.

All is good, except that `Config.load()` (the one that loads the before mentioned files) does asynchronous requests, thus, when I try to use my `config.get('myConfigValue')` method, it throws an exception, as `Config._config` is not initialized yet.

What is the correct way to do this?

I’m using Angular 2.0.0 RC6. Below is my `config.ts` file.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class Config {
    private _config: Object = null;
    private _env: Object = null;

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    load() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get("app/config/env.json")
                .map(res => res.json())
                .subscribe((env_data) => {
                    this._env = env_data;

                    this.http.get("app/config/" + env_data.env + ".json")
                        .map(res => res.json())
                        .catch((error: any) => {
                            console.error(error);

                            return Observable.throw(error.json().error || `Server error`);
                        })
                        .subscribe((data) => {
                            this._config = data;
                            resolve(true);
                        });
                });
        });
    }

    getEnv(key: any) {
        return this._env[key];
    }

    get(key: any) {
        return this._config[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method/37611614#37611614 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033835/angularjs2-preload-server-configuration-before-the-application-starts/39033958#39033958

Comment: I wonder why my search-fu didn’t bring up these… I ran through them and they seem to be good for me. If so, I’ll close this question.