# Angular 2 how to make child component wait for async data to be ready

Tags: angular

I'm passing async data from a parent component to a child component. And the child component needs to know the length of the data in order to do something.

How the problem is that the child component can't use the 'Oninit' hook to do work because the data isn't available at this time. So how do I do this?

The parent component code looks like:

```js
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `<div>
                    <child [items]="items | async">
                </div>`
})

export class Parent implements OnInit {

    items: Items[];

    constructor(
        private itemService: ItemService,
        private router: Router
    ) { }    

    ngOnInit() {
        this.itemService.getItemss()
            .subscribe(
                items => this.items = items,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
            );
    }

}
```

And the child component looks like:

```js
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'child',    
    template: `<div>
                    <div *ngFor="let itemChunk of itemChunks"></div>
                    content here
                </div>`
})
export class child implements OnInit{
    @Input() items: Items[];
    itemChunks: Items[][];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.itemChunks = this.chunk(this.Items);
    }

    chunk(items: Items[]) {
        let result = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i += 6) { // this line causes the problem since 'items' is undefined
            result.push(items.slice(i, i + 6));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

What is the best practice to handle this?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

There are three ways to do this:

1. Put an `*ngIf` in parent. Only render child when parent's `items` is ready.

```html
<div *ngIf="items">
   <child [items]="items | async">
</div>
```

2. Separate your input `getter` `setter` in child. Then act whenever the value is set, you can use RxJS `BehaviorSubject` also.

```js
private _items = new BehaviorSubject<Items[]>([]);

@Input() set items(value: Items[]) { 
    this._items.next(value); 
}

get items() {
   return this._items.getValue();
}

ngOnInit() {
    this._items.subscribe(x => {
       this.chunk(x);
    })
}
```

3. Do it during the `ngOnChanges` of the child. Refer to here for example. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#onchanges

Comment: End up taking option 2. Behaves exactly as expected. Thanks very Much.

Comment: @Milad, sorry? I don't understand you.

Comment: @Milad, if you care enough to check the answered datetime, you'll find that Chybie answered earlier than you. Hence, I marked his answer as accepted.

Comment: value setter would be enough, but I like the Observable flavour :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It's 'obvious' after seeing it but it eluded me for part of today.

Comment: I used option 1 with the *ngIf but I needed to leave off the async pipe or I got "Invalid argument for pipe 'AsyncPipe'"

Comment: What is this.chunk(x);?

Answer (score 13):

Simpler solution:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['items'].currentValue) {
        this.items = items
    }
}
```

Comment: It is worth to mention, that **ngOnChanges** will run before **ngOnInit**.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a setter :

```
export class child implements OnInit{
    itemChunks: Items[][];

    private _items ;

    //bellow  will get called when ever the items are passed in by the parent component
    @Input( 'items' ) set items ( items: Items[] ) {
       this._items = items;

       this.itemChunks = this.chunk(this._items);
    }




    chunk(items: Items[]) {
        let result = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i += 6) { // this line causes the problem since 'items' is undefined
            result.push(items.slice(i, i + 6));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

---

---

---

Any by the way, I feel like your parent component is not right as well, it should be :

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `<div>
                    <child [items]="items | async">
                </div>`
})

export class Parent implements OnInit {

    items: Items[];

    constructor(
        private itemService: ItemService,
        private router: Router
    ) { 
         this.items = this.itemService.getItemss(); // if getItemss is returning an observable, which I think it does
     }    

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the itemService doesn't return observatable at the moment. It might in the future.