# Angular value coming to Child Component template but coming as undefined in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, angular-components, ngoninit

When I pass the value to child component values coming in template but not showing in ngOnInit of child component

parent Component

```
<div class="overview bg-blue-pattern">prospectId {{prospectId}}
        <app-calls-log-history [prospectid]="prospectId"></app-calls-log-history>
    </div>
```

Child Componnet

```
<div class="calls-log-history-container">
        prospectId {{prospectid}}
    </div>
```

Child component ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactFilterService } from '../../../../services/contact.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calls-log-history',
  templateUrl: './calls-log-history.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calls-log-history.component.scss']
})
export class CallsLogHistoryComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() prospectid: any;
  CallsLogHistory: Array<any> = [];
  constructor( private _contactFilterService: ContactFilterService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('prospectid : '+ this.prospectid); // coming as undefined
    this._contactFilterService.getCallsLogHistory(this.prospectid).subscribe(
        result => {
            this.CallsLogHistory = result.notes;
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389124/angular-2-how-to-make-child-component-wait-for-asyn-data-to-be-ready/41389243#41389243

Answer (score 2):

short answer, using `*ngIf`

```
<div class="overview bg-blue-pattern" *ngIf="prospectId">prospectId {{prospectId}}
    <app-calls-log-history [prospectid]="prospectId"></app-calls-log-history>
</div>
```

long answer, this happen because your `prospectId` is initially nothing until you called an async method and bind it. Child component already `init` one time when the `prospectId` is nothing.

Refer to this post for details: https://scotch.io/tutorials/3-ways-to-pass-async-data-to-angular-2-child-components#toc-solution-3-use-rxjs-behaviorsubject