# Why does object in callback from the subscribe function keeps getting undefined?

Tags: angular, parent-child

I'm struggling with the subscribe function in Angular. I know this function works asynchronous as JavaScript will run the next pieces of code, until the REST call response is retrieved.

So I made a console.log in this subscription function:

```
export class MachineConfiguratorComponent implements OnInit {

  itemId: any;
  machine: Machine;

  constructor(
    private configuratorService: ConfiguratorService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(param => this.itemId = param.get('id'));

    this.configuratorService.getMachineDetails(this.itemId).subscribe((res) => {
      this.machine = res;
      console.log("response in parent is: " + this.machine.description);
    });
  }
}
```

But the response still is undefined:
[image]

If I place another line of code behind the subscribe function to print the machine name, it gives an error because the machine is still undefined. That sounds logic to me, because the object isn't retrieved from the call yet.
But why is the object in the callback even undefined? Am I missing something?

I mean I can pass the machine to the child component and place {{machine?.name}} in the HTML, but how can I make sure the child component is certain for the object to be defined? Because in the child component itself i can't use this.machine?.name, so it always gives an error unless the machine is defined. I only see examples with normal strings where they have to put '' around the string itself or so, but this is an object retrieved from a REST-call..

**Update**

This is the response:
[image]

See parent:

```
export class MachineConfiguratorComponent implements OnInit {

machine: Machine;

constructor(
    private configuratorService: ConfiguratorService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(param => {
      this.configuratorService.getMachineDetails(param.get('id')).subscribe((res) => {
        this.machine = res;
        console.log("response in parent is: ", res);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

See HTML:

```
    <app-machinedetails-overview [inputMachine]="machine"></app-machinedetails-overview>
```

But when I call it in the child component with the @Input it still gives undefined.

This is the child:

```
export class MachinedetailsOverviewComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() inputMachine: Machine;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("child gives: ", this.inputMachine)
  }
}
```

This is the console:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular - two subscriptions in ngOnInit result in object 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55638147/angular-two-subscriptions-in-ngoninit-result-in-object-undefined)

Comment: @Salomé You tried to edit an answer to include more information there, but you shouldn't. Please edit your question instead and add the information at its end.

Comment: Right thanks! Will pay attention to it next time. Asking questions the right way is hard, still learning. Excuses for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `this.route.paramMap` and `this.configuratorService.getMachineDetails` will run asynchronously at this point.

Call `this.configuratorService.getMachineDetails` inside the first `subscribe`, so that `this.configuratorService.getMachineDetails` can wait for the `itemId` to get set.

Something like this:

```
export class MachineConfiguratorComponent implements OnInit {

  itemId: any;
  machine: Machine;

  constructor(
    private configuratorService: ConfiguratorService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(param => {
      this.itemId = param.get('id');
      this.configuratorService.getMachineDetails(this.itemId).subscribe((res) => {
        this.machine = res;
        console.log("response in parent is: " + this.machine.description);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**Update**

This is the restcall method in the service:

`getMachineDetails(machineId: string):Observable<Machine>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Machine> (${this.baseUrl+this.machineUrl}/${machineId});
  }`

This is the ngOnInit after answers:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(param => {
  this.configuratorService.getMachineDetails(param.get('id')).subscribe((res) => {
    // this.machine = res;
    console.log("response in parent is: " + res.description);
  });
});
```

}

**UPDATE:**

Since you want to use the `machine` as an `@Input` property to your child component, you'll pass it like this:

```
<app-machinedetails-overview 
  [inputMachine]="machine">
</app-machinedetails-overview>
```

But since the machine data is being retrieved by making an API call, initially the machine will be undefined. And only when the API call succeeds and you get the machine, then Angular's Change Detection Mechanism will kick in and update `[inputMachine]="machine"` data binding.

Now, in your `MachinedetailsOverviewComponent`, `ngOnInit` only runs once, after the first `ngOnChanges`. So by the time `ngOnInit` runs, machine would still be undefined. Hence `inputMachine` would still be undefined.

So ideally you will get the updated value in `ngOnChanges`

Make the following changes to your `MachinedetailsOverviewComponent`:

```
export class MachinedetailsOverviewComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() inputMachine: Machine;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log("child gives: ", this.inputMachine)
  }
}
```

Hope the explanation makes it clear.

Comment: that sounds logic of course and I did this, but the response still gives me the machine undefined..

Comment: Con you console res value ?

Comment: I've added this:     console.log("response in parent is: " + res.description);    but still gives undefined, and only res gives [Object object].

Comment: That gives me indeed the full object, can it be because my model attributes start lowercase and the JSON object with uppercase?

Comment: I've updated it, but it calls the child even asynchronous. I don't know how to make the input wait for the object

Comment: For any attribute in the object, but I want to pass it to the child component and read it there. Although the child component doesn't wait for the subscription, that's mostly the problem. With the small mistakes i made to print the object with '+' and having models with lowercase attributes.

Comment: It's probably done by onChanges, as been explained here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389124/angular-2-how-to-make-child-component-wait-for-asyn-data-to-be-ready)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time! I've edited the question with a summary of our 'journey'. :)