# Angular 2 pre-rendering data

Tags: angular

I ever wandered if with `Angular 2`, is it possible to prerender `data` then show the page which contains those data?
Let I explain what I want:

1. **First step:**

I click on a link, the url change but the current page doesn't show again until the data is fully loaded. (I don't want to show gif loader.) It's like a timeout until data is loaded.

2. **Second step:**

When data is loaded, I want to display the page which contains those data.

Is there a way to realize this with `Angualr 2`?

Could somebody give me a link that can explain me this concept?

**N.B**: I found this: [What is best way to load json settings from the server?](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9047#issuecomment-224075188) but I don't really understand how to add this into my code.

This too: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/APP_INITIALIZER-let.html but there's no example or more explaination into the official website.

**Update**

The picture above will show what I want:

[image]

Thanx in advanced.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what part you don't understand. Here are another examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033835/angularjs2-preload-server-configuration-before-the-application-starts/39033958#39033958

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I will draw something and update my question

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I add a little scene with this updated question. If you can help me! Thanx!

Comment: You can just use `<div [hidden]="!isDataArrived">` to hide the view until the data has arrived and Angular has rendered the view. There might be more to when exactly to set `isDataArrived` to true depending on how exactly you fetch and render the data.

Comment: It may work,  but you know, if the current page has many text, and click on link, I don't want to navigate to the page corresponding with the clicked link until his data is loaded.
Because if I use `<div [hidden]="!isDataArrived">`, it will be show the page corresponding to the clicked link but hide the content, until `isDataArrived` is true. And the page from where i click the link will be immedialty replaced by the content of clicked link.

Another way?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you want.

Comment: I made an application with angular 2, http://preprod.thedoorman.immo:3000/le-concept-the-door-man.html

And if you click on **Location** link, it just change the url and still stay on the link I gave, but If the data into **Location** link is loaded, at that I will display the content of **Location** link.

I change **club** link with **location** because club link is static page.

May it help you to understant what I want! Thanx @GünterZöchbauer