# Inject Http manually in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I want to manually bootstrap an Angular 4 app (created with CLI).
In `main.ts` I am doing this:

```
const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
  Http,
  BrowserXhr,
  {provide: RequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions},
  {provide: ResponseOptions, useClass: BaseResponseOptions},
  {provide: ConnectionBackend, useClass: XHRBackend},
  {provide: XSRFStrategy, useFactory: () => new CookieXSRFStrategy()},
]);
const http = injector.get(Http);

http.get('assets/configs/configuration.json')
  .map((res: Response) => {
    return res.json();
  }).subscribe((config: Configuration) => {
  configuration = config;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(configuration));
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
});
```

I seem to get a valid Http instance but when I use it (`http.get`) I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCookie' of null
    at CookieXSRFStrategy.webpackJsonp.../../../http/@angular/http.es5.js.CookieXSRFStrategy.configureRequest (vendor.bundle.js:141626)
```

My http object looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You can do that with `http` provided by Angular. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45205562/2545680). I'm also curios where you use `ConfigurationService`, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Try this solution, it worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461852/inject-a-service-manually

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `HttpClient` service before the Angular starts using `ReflectiveInjector` like this:

```
import { ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(getAnnotations(HttpClientModule)[0].providers);

const http = injector.get(HttpClient);
http.get('/posts/1').subscribe((r) => {
  ConfigurationService.configuration = <Configuration>JSON.parse(config);
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
});
```

This line:

```
getAnnotations(HttpClientModule).providers
```

references all providers that are registered on the `HttpClientModule` so you don't have to specify them manually. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45276490/2545680) explains the `getAnnotations` function in great details.

The approach I've shown is "sort of" the similar to what you're doing when importing `HttpClientModule` into the `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [HttpClientModule, ...],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

See [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/29XWrJd959gNrAzIM76N?p=preview) for details.

Comment: Thanks, Maximus. This looks like the kind of code that might change with the next version. I think I'll stick with my solution for now. However, your submission answers my question and I'll mark it as accepted (although I haven't tried it).

Comment: you're welcome, you can accept or upvote my answer if it helped. Also can you show how you use `ConfigurationService`

Comment: @hholtij, thanks. There are only two pieces here that might be affected by the update `httpFactory` and `_createDefaultCookieXSRFStrategy` functions. It's theoretically possible to try to find a way to not use them, at least `_createDefaultCookieXSRFStrategy`. Everything else is publicly supported and if it changes then you'll have to update all code that uses `http` inside the Angular app as well. Also I'm still interested in `ConfigurationService`. Do you then use it as a provider somewhere?

Comment: ConfigurationService used to be the service that read the config file. We are now using the NSwagStudio tool to auto-generate api services from the swagger definitions. It works very well but necessitates reading the config file before bootstrapping the app as it contains the api urls. Now, ConfigurationService is basically just a class with a static property. Might change that as well.

Comment: I just tried your solution, Maximus. It doesn't work for me. I get the same error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCookie' of null
    at CookieXSRFStrategy.webpackJsonp.../../../http/@angular/http.es5.js.CookieXSRFStrategy.configureRequest

Comment: @hholtij, yeah, the previous `http` implementation depended on the some DOM related stuff which wasn't available before the Angular starts. The new `HttpClient` available in the `4.3.0` seems to not have that dependency and works fine for me. Just tested it and updated the answer. Check it

Comment: I am using the latest 4.3.1 and there is no 'decorators' property on HttpClientModule. Your code does not work with 4.3.1.

Comment: [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/29XWrJd959gNrAzIM76N?p=preview) shows that everything is working fine on `4.3.1`

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com `ReflectiveInjector` is being deprecated.  How would you do this with `StaticInjector`?

Comment: @c1moore, same way `new StaticInjector(getAnnotations(HttpClientModule)[0].providers)`

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com I tried that with `Injector.create()`, which is what I think you meant by `new StaticInjector`, but it doesn't work (`Error: StaticInjectorError[HttpClient]: Function/Class not supported`).  I can't find anything about `StaticInjector` in the actual documentation.

Comment: @c1moore, why are you trying this?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com This might be a conversation better suited for [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160461/inject-httpclient-with-staticinjector).

Comment: @c1moore, I don't have time now, maybe post a new question

Comment: The answer was actually quite simple.  There really was no need to use `HttpClient` at all.  I eventually just created a wrapper around it since all async operations are caught by Angular (via Zones).

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com I am using the same code with static injector it is saying `StaticInjectorError[HttpClient]: Function/Class not supported` same as @c1moore ? and @c1moore did you figure that stuff out ?

Comment: @fastAsTortoise Yes, I just used `XMLHttpRequest` directly.  Angular Zones will catch the async request and everything will work automagically.  I did create a simple wrapper around `XMLHttpRequest`, though, that implements the same interface as `HttpClient`.  Let me know if that makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

As another approach you can use the native browser [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). So you do not have to deal with angular http, etc

That is how I am doing that:

```
fetch(configUrl, { method: 'get' })
.then((response) => {
  response.json()
    .then((data: any) => {
      if (environment.production) {
        enableProdMode();
      };
      platformBrowserDynamic([{ provide: AppSettings, useValue: new AppSettings(data.config) }]).bootstrapModule(AppModule);
    });
});
```

But bare in mind that [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) didn't get much love in [old browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch) so you need to polyfil that with [whatwg-fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) like `npm install whatwg-fetch --save` then `import 'whatwg-fetch'` in `polyfills.ts` in order if you want to support old browsers.

**UPDATE:**
Yeah you can use [XMLHttpRequest](https://caniuse.com/#search=XMLHttpRequest) but you are getting same browsers support with that as [fetch](https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch) just a modern replacement for [XMLHttpRequest](https://caniuse.com/#search=XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: but he's creating them with Injector, he doesn't depend on the framework to provide them

Comment: @Maximus ahh, I wasn't aware of that, thanks for letting know, but can see at least one downside - it is like 3 times more code ;)

Comment: Yeah, sure, because `http` provided by `Angular` does a lot more than `fetch` :)

Comment: it should also be noted that this approach is more future-safe I think

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the original answer worked before, but in Angular 5 I was not able to use it, there was no definition for the function `getAnnotations`.  This is what did work for me however:

```
import { ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpClient,
  XhrFactory,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpXhrBackend,
  HttpBackend
} from '@angular/common/http';

// https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L45
export class BrowserXhr implements XhrFactory {
  build(): any { return <any>(new XMLHttpRequest()); }
}

const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
  HttpClient,
  HttpXhrBackend,
  { provide: HttpBackend, useExisting: HttpXhrBackend },
  { provide: HttpHandler, useExisting: HttpBackend },
  { provide: XhrFactory, useClass: BrowserXhr},
]);

const http: HttpClient = injector.get(HttpClient);

http.get('/url').subscribe((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Kuncevic. I have come up with this solution, which works fine:

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback) {
  const xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200) {
      callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
  }

  xmlHttp.open('GET', theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}

httpGetAsync('assets/configs/configuration.json', (config: string) => {
  ConfigurationService.configuration = <Configuration>JSON.parse(config);
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
});
```