# Angular 4 load data before initialize the application

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-router-guards

I'm trying to load some data before my application starts. The reason why I need to do it, is because some of the menu has restricted access based on some user condition, for example, based on the user location.

So if the user doesn't have a location yet or it's location isn't enabled to access certain view, I need to block it.

---

I tried to use Angular Resolve method, without success, this is what I did:

**Resolve guard**

```
// The apiService is my own service to make http calls to the server.
@Injectable()
export class AppResolveGuard implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(
        private _api: ApiService,
        private _store: Store<IStoreInterface>,
    ) { }

    resolve(): any {
        return this._api.apiGet('loadData').subscribe(response => {
            this._store.dispatch({
                type: USER_FETCH_DATA,
                payload: response.usuario
            });

            return response;
        });
    }
}
```

**Routing**

```
export const routing = [
    {
        path: '', component: AppComponent, canActivateChild: [AuthGuard], resolve: {app: AppResolveGuard},
        children: [
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'company', canActivate: [LocationGuard], component: CompanyComponent },
        ]
    }
];
```

> The AuthGuard is just going to check for a valid cookie session.

As you can see, the routing I'm trying to block access is the `company` routing.
I'm able to prevent access when I first load another page, for example, if the first access is to the page `home` and then I navigate to the page `company` the validation works fine, because the user data and location is already avaliable.

However, if the first access is to the page `company`, it will block all users to navigate there, because at the time the `LocationGuard` try to validate the user location, the data isn't avaliable yet.

I also tried to replace `Resolve` with `CanActivate`, but it never enables the view after the data is avaliable, it stays on a blank page.

Comment: try to look in to this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/45204693/415078 basically you can call you api before you bootstrap AppModule and then you can pass/access that data up in your guards

Comment: @Kuncevic cant it be solved using the angular router? Because it's all linked with the store, etc..

Comment: Then sounds like you cant do that before app initialize as you rely on store, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425461/angular2-canactivate-calling-async-function).

I found a way to use `canActivate`. I had already tried to use `.map()` to return an `Observable`, but the key point is the `.first()` at the end, this is waht solved the issue.

I'll keep it open tho, because if there is a way to achieve the same result using `Resolve`, maybe it is better.

Answer (score 12):

A few things ...

Pre-fetching data before a page loads is a great use of a resolver.

Preventing access to a route is a great use of CanActivate.

Note however that the resolver only works AFTER all guards are checked. So your code will attempt to run the CanActivate *before* running the resolver.

[image]

Comment: Hum.. So going with canActivate (like I'm commenting on my own answer here) is the way to go?

Comment: I don't understand your requirements well enough. But one option is to add the resolve to the parent route and the canActivate onto the child routes. That way the resolve should execute before the child's canActivate's run.

Comment: @DeborahK can you help me to locate where this schema is in the official documentation of Angular? I easily find the schema for component lifecycles but I don't reach to find the one you provided regarding guards and resolvers .

Comment: It is somewhat discussed here: https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#milestone-5-route-guards Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use `APP_INITIALIZER` to load data before application starts.

Check this article:

https://devblog.dymel.pl/2017/10/17/angular-preload/