# How to use existing Angular service in React?

Tags: angular, reactjs, react-tsx

I am an absolute beginner to React. I am creating a simple react app with App Component only and I have own angular library (NPM package) with a simple service. 
And Angular service has some dependencies injected into its constructor.

I tried using [inversifyJs](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS) but had no luck. I am getting the following error.

[image]

and here is my react code - **corelib** is my own library

**App.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import "reflect-metadata";
import { TYPES, myContainer } from "./container-config";
import { CorelibService } from 'corelib'
import { inject } from 'inversify'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  @inject(TYPES.CORE_LIB) hostService: CorelibService;
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const ninja = myContainer.get<CorelibService>(TYPES.CORE_LIB);
    console.log('ninja', ninja);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Welcome to React App</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**container-config.ts**

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { Container, decorate, injectable } from 'inversify';
import { CorelibService, MyService } from 'corelib';

const TYPES = {
    CORE_LIB: Symbol.for("HostAppIntegration"),
    MY_SERVICE: Symbol.for("MyService")
};
export { TYPES }

decorate(injectable(), CorelibService);
decorate(injectable(), MyService);

const myContainer = new Container();
myContainer.bind<CorelibService>(TYPES.CORE_LIB).to(CorelibService);
myContainer.bind<MyService>(TYPES.MY_SERVICE).to(MyService);
export { myContainer };
```

**here is Angular code**

**Corelib.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './my.serivce';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CorelibService {

  constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

  public sayHello() {
    console.log('Hello from sample angular library');
    this.myService.sayHi();
  }
}
```

**my.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MyService {
    constructor() {
        console.log('my service');
    }
    public sayHi() {
        console.log('Hi from sample angular library - my service');
    }
}
```

I don't understand, what am I mssing here? or

Is it really possible to use Angular service in react?

Comment: You cannot use Inversify decorators in React component classes because they aren't instantiated by Inversify. Access a container directly. Also it's unclear how this is related to Angular. Angular and Inversify DI look similar but they aren't compatible.

Comment: @estus How this is related to Angular? - my library uses angular DI feature.

Comment: @estus It means I cannot use NPM package that has Angular reference.

Comment: I see. But I don't understand why you're using Inversify when you need to use Angular.

Comment: Look hire: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408694/connect-angular-application-with-reactjs-app/54408718#54408718

Answer (score 1):

Angular injector should be retrieved to access services, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50123539/3731501):

```
@NgModule({ imports: [BrowserModule] })
export class AppModule {
  ngDoBootstrap() {}  
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    const appModule = await platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
    const myService = appModule.injector.get(MyService);
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

It's impossible to use `@inject` decorators on React component class because a class is instantiated by React, not by Angular or Inversify.

Inversify was inspired by Angular DI but they aren't compatible and shouldn't be mixed. If `MyService` was registered as a service with Angular `Injectable`, it should be retrieved from Angular, not Inversify container.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible if you are using Typescript in React. You are using inversify for DI?

Comment: Please use the answers for actual solitions and write comments for asking more details. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer