# How to use (angular) HTTP Client in native background service - NativeScript

Tags: android, angular, typescript, nativescript

How can i use an angular http client in my background service (android).

My app needs to send the data from the background service to my server.

Im using NativeScript / Angular.

My Background Service

```
declare var android;

if (application.android) {
    (<any>android.app.Service).extend("org.tinus.Example.BackgroundService", {
        onStartCommand: function (intent, flags, startId) {
            this.super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
            return android.app.Service.START_STICKY;
        },
        onCreate: function () {
            let that = this;

            geolocation.enableLocationRequest().then(function () {
                that.id = geolocation.watchLocation(
                    function (loc) {

                        if (loc) {
                            // should send to server from here

                        }
                    },
                    function (e) {
                        console.log("Background watchLocation error: " + (e.message || e));
                    },
                    {
                        desiredAccuracy: Accuracy.high,
                        updateDistance: 5,
                        updateTime: 5000,
                        minimumUpdateTime: 100
                    });
            }, function (e) {
                console.log("Background enableLocationRequest error: " + (e.message || e));
            });
        },
        onBind: function (intent) {
            console.log("on Bind Services");
        },
        onUnbind: function (intent) {
            console.log('UnBind Service');
        },
        onDestroy: function () {
            geolocation.clearWatch(this.id);
        }
    });
}
```

Two approaches i tried.

(1). Using Injector to inject my service

```
         const injector = Injector.create([ { provide: ExampleService, useClass: ExampleService, deps: [HttpClient] }]);
         const service = injector.get(ExampleService);
         console.log(service.saveDriverLocation); // This prints
         service.saveDriverLocation(new GeoLocation(loc.latitude, loc.longitude, loc.horizontalAccuracy, loc.altitude), ['id']); // This complains
```

Issue for (1)

```
System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
```

(2). Using Native code

```
     let url = new java.net.URL("site/fsc");
     let connection = null;
     try {
          connection = url.openConnection();
     } catch (error) {
           console.log(error);
     }

     connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
     let out = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
     let writer = new java.io.BufferedWriter(new java.io.OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
     let data = 'mutation NewDriverLoc{saveDriverLocation(email:"' + (<SystemUser>JSON.parse(getString('User'))).email + '",appInstanceId:' + (<ApplicationInstance>JSON.parse(getString('appInstance'))).id + ',geoLocation:{latitude:' + loc.latitude + ',longitude:' + loc.longitude + ',accuracy:' + loc.horizontalAccuracy + '}){id}}';
     writer.write(data);
     writer.flush();
     writer.close();
     out.close();
     connection.connect();
```

Issue for (2)

```
System.err: Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

So basically the first approach is angular, issue is that im not injecting all the needed services / not sure how.

Second approach is native, and the issue is the network is on the main thread. I need to use AsyncTask just not sure how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at this link
[How do I fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-do-i-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception/9289190#9289190)

Add the following to your native code like you mention in option 2. And it should work

```
let policy = new 
android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Buiilder().permitAll().build();
andriod.os.StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: This worked, but feels hacky to use sockets on the main thread

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [ReflectiveInjector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45205562), but remember to use NativeScriptHttpClientModule. I haven't tried it, so I can't say it'll work.

What I ended up using was the [non-angular Http module](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/http). It's a bit hacky to not use services, but it works.

### Edit (June/2019)

In the example below I was using `BrowserXhr` from the deprecated `@angular/http` package. I've updated to use the private angular API instead. The example has been updated.

### Edit (April/2019)

So I ended up actually needing this and managed to inject the HttpClient in a non-angular application. This should also work with background services and workers.

```
import { HttpBackend, HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, XhrFactory, ɵangular_packages_common_http_http_d as BrowserXhr, ɵHttpInterceptingHandler } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { NSFileSystem } from "nativescript-angular/file-system/ns-file-system";
import { NsHttpBackEnd } from "nativescript-angular/http-client/ns-http-backend";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class TestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log("intercepted", req);
        return next.handle(req);
    }


}

const httpClientInjector = Injector.create([
    {
        provide: HttpClient, useClass: HttpClient, deps: [
            HttpHandler
        ]
    },
    { provide: HttpHandler, useClass: ɵHttpInterceptingHandler, deps: [HttpBackend, Injector] },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TestInterceptor, multi: true, deps: [] }, // remove or copy this line to remove/add more interceptors
    { provide: HttpBackend, useExisting: NsHttpBackEnd },
    { provide: NsHttpBackEnd, useClass: NsHttpBackEnd, deps: [XhrFactory, NSFileSystem] },
    { provide: XhrFactory, useExisting: BrowserXhr },
    { provide: BrowserXhr, useClass: BrowserXhr, deps: [] },
    { provide: NSFileSystem, useClass: NSFileSystem, deps: [] }
]);

export const httpClient = httpClientInjector.get(HttpClient);
```

Note that I'm also leveraging Interceptors.

This implementation is missing `HttpClientXsrfModule`, so you'll have to add it yourself if you intend to use it. That said, it seems XHR cookies are not currently supported: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2424

If you want to use a service like:

```
export class MyService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

You can add to the top of the array (after `Injector.create[`) the following:

`{ provide: MyService, useClass: MyService, deps: [HttpClient] }` (remeber that deps must be in the order required by your constructor!)

and then, you get your service by calling `const myService = httpClientInjector.get(MyService);`

Comment: @TinusJackson I've update my response. This way you should be able to use Nativescript's HttpClient. I managed to use HttpClient on a blank app with plain TS (not in an angular application)