# cordova + angular: how to use angular router module in main.ts file

Tags: angular, cordova, android-lifecycle, angular-router, onresume

in my cordova app i catch the `onResume` event in the `main.ts` file, and there i need, under certain conditions, to navigate to home screen of my app. For that i'am trying to inject the `RouterModule` into this application entry point file, but have problem with this injection.

i successfully injected the `HttpClientModule` according to [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45205562/7312183), but i can't inject the `RouterModule` in the same way.

here is my `main.ts` file:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

let onDeviceReady = () => {
   document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
}

let onResume = () => {
   ...
   // here i need the Router and use it like: router.navigate(['home'])
   ...
}
```

and here is my router defined in the `app.module.ts`:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFaundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
   ...
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)]
   ...
)}
export class AppModule { }
```

and in any component or service in my app i can use the `Router` like that:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable, forwardRef, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DemoService {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

   NavigateHome() {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
   }
}
```

so, is there a way to get that ability of Router navigation in the `main.ts` file?

alternatively, is there a better location for catching this device events in an angular application, so i can easily use the `Router`?

Thanks!