# Angular 2 Set APP_BASE_HREF with a value from a Promise / Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, aot

I try to set the APP_BASE_HREF in the "CoreModule" with a value from a async rest call.
I can't see how this is done, because the provide method needs to return a string.

for example:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        HttpModule
    ],
    ...
    providers: [
        ...
        ...
        BackendRequestClass,
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useFactory: () => () => return '/some/path', deps: [], multi: true }
    ],
});
```

but when I need the value from a webservice, I can't return the string.
Any ideas how this could be done?

thx

Answer (score 7):

I tried your solution.
The problem is, that at the time

```
{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useFactory: (config) => config.appBaseHref, deps: [ConfigService] }
```

the config.appBaseHref is not set yet.
When I debug the code I see, that the `APP_INITIALIZER` is executed after the provider from `APP_BASE_HREF`

That causes, that the `BASE_HREF` is not set.

Answer (score 4):

We had the same challenge: Set the `APP_BASE_HREF` dynamically, based on a result from an async API call to allow routing of an app which can be accessed through different URLs.

While the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46190405/388827) presented by Günter looks sweet, it unfortunately did not work, at least with Angular 7. In our case, `APP_BASE_HREF` always took precedence over `APP_INITIALIZER`, so we couldn’t initialize the `APP_BASE_HREF` based on the resolved promise value returned from the initializer.

Instead, I implemented the API call to happen before the Angular bootstrapping and then injected the provider so that it’s available within the Angular context.

Adding to `main.ts`:

```
fetchConfig().then(config => {
  platformBrowserDynamic([ { provide: ConfigData, useValue: config } ])
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

We can then configure the `APP_BASE_HREF` in the `providers` within `app.module.ts`:

```
providers: [
  // …
  { 
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF, 
    useFactory: (config: ConfigData) => config.base, 
    deps: [ ConfigData ] 
  }
]
```

**[edit 2019-08-21]** Clarification per the comments: `fetchConfig()` is the API request which gets the configuration and returns a `Promise`. And `ConfigData` is not an Angular service, but just a simple class which gets instantiated in `fetchConfig()` and which gives me type safety when accessing it later in my application:

```
function fetchConfig (): Promise<ConfigData> {
  return fetch('/api/config')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => new ConfigData(response));
}
```

Comment: Rather than going "outside" Angular, you might be able to use the PLATFORM_INITIALIZER mechanism to fetch the config. This kicks in nice and early (certainly before APP_INITIALIZER).
`platformBrowserDynamic([{
  provide: PLATFORM_INITIALIZER,
  useValue: fetchConfig,
  multi: true
}]).bootstrapModule(AppModule)`

Comment: @GaryMcGill Thanks for the input -- I'll give it a try once I have some spare minutes!

Comment: @qqilihq can I see the code for fetchConfig()?  Where are you defining config  in main.ts ?

Comment: @Arnold.Krumins It's just an HTTP request which fetches the config and resolves to a promise.

Comment: @qqilihq ok thanks. ConfigData is a Service? If so, how did you create it in main.ts?

Comment: No, not a service. It's just a simple class.

Comment: @qqilihq I see. So how does app.module.ts know about this class? Is it static?

Comment: @GaryMcGill Again thanks for the suggestion from July. Actually I just had some spare time to give this a try. Unfortunately `PLATFORM_INITIALIZER` doesn’t seem to support “waiting” for a promise (which would be necessary to await `fetchConfig()`). Anything I’m missing or misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `APP_INITIALIZER` to get the path in advance and then use a dependency as shown in [Angularjs2 - preload server configuration before the application starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033835/angularjs2-preload-server-configuration-before-the-application-starts/39033958#39033958)

```
export function loadConfig(config: ConfigService) => () => config.load()

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule,
        routes,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule],
    providers: [
        ConfigService,
        BackendRequestClass,
        { provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
          useFactory: loadConfig,
          deps: [ConfigService], 
          multi: true },
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useFactory: (config) => config.appBaseHref, deps: [ConfigService] }

    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The `ConfigService` can inject `BackendRequestClass` or `Http` and fetch the data and then make it available using its `appBaseHref` property (just an example how it could be done).

Comment: This looks like a good solution in theory, however, `APP_BASE_HREF` seems to get executed *before* `APP_INITIALIZER` (at least on newer Angular versions -- I'm using 7). Has this changed, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I haven't worked with Angular since a while and also don't know.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly common problem. But she could not get enough votes for the Angular team to take her on:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25932

Tried many ways. But apparently the only solution is to change maint.ts. I slightly modified the approach that qqilihq suggested:

**main.ts:**

```
(function fetchConfig (): Promise<any> {
  return fetch('/apiTrendz/publicApi/info')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      platformBrowserDynamic(
        [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, 
         useValue: response.baseHrefFromBack ? '/' + response.baseHrefFromBack + '/'
```

: '/default-base-url/'}])
.bootstrapModule(AppModule)
.catch(err => {
console.error(err)
});
});
})();

Note that here we are `bootstrapModule(AppModule)`, which was before in code by default, is now executed after the request is executed. And we will provide `APP_BASE_HREF` right here, so you won’t need to do anything in the module.

Also, please note that baseHref must be wrapped in slashes (/baseHref/), otherwise you can see a redirect to the main page later when reloading the page with other routes.