# Resolve HttpComponent result inside Service

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-observable

Consider the typical HttpClient example

*In Service*

```
  config: string[];

  load(): Observable<string[]> {
     return this.http.get<string[]>('./assets/config.json');
  }

  getConfig(key: string): string {
     if (!this.config) {
        this.load.subscribe(data => this.config = data);
     }
     return this.config[key];
  }
```

*In Component*

```
 value = myService.getConfig('blah');
```

Obviously, this example **doesn't** work because `return` in `getConfig()` happens before `config` is getting populated in `subscribe()`.

All examples show `subscribe()` in the calling component. But how do I await the return *inside* the service?

**NOTE** This is just MCVE. In reality, the use case is much more complex and is *not* how to get the values before application starts. For example, I need to get a large array from the server, and *in the service* filter based on some criteria and return to component.

Comment: You can use async and await, but actually i would suggest the following: if you will call the config api only once and then state the response in your service, you should do it on the service constructor.

Comment: sorry - I should have mentioned: I tried in constructor, but the result is the same... Looks like the service isn't instantiated until it is injected in the component and even though there is `subscribe()` in the constructor, my `getConfig()` still returns undefined or empty array...

Comment: Yes you are right, the services is not instantiated until it's first inject, and sorry for the below comment but you do not forget this.config right ? if(!config) => if (!this.config) and so the return value "return this.config[key]"

Comment: yes, the typo is in the question; not in my code :) (I fixed the question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs2 - preload server configuration before the application starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033835/angularjs2-preload-server-configuration-before-the-application-starts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

your service:

```
async getConfig(key: string): Promise<number> {
  if (!this.config) {
     const response = await this.load().toPromise();
     this.config = response.json();
  }
  return this.config[key];
}
```

your component:

```
async ngOnInit() {
  let config = await this.yourService.getConfig('blah');
}
```

Comment: I think we are close... However, I am getting `TS2339: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Subscription'`. and I see in debugger that `return` still happens before `subscribe()`

Comment: I have updated my answer, would you give a try and update me please.

Comment: `.json()` still doesn't work - but it's not important! It works the way I expected all along: `await` actually `await`s. That is, it doesn't continue until `toPromise()` completes. And `response` in your example would be a number (in mine it's an array of key:value objects. I am not sure what I was doing wrong before but I can't reproduce the problem any more!

Comment: Glad to help :).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, its recommended to use resolvers https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

you can customize this and no need to import route args

```
    @Injectable()
class TeamResolver implements Resolve<Team> {
  constructor(private backend: Backend) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    return this.backend.fetchTeam(route.params.id);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'team/:id',
        component: TeamCmp,
        resolve: {
          team: TeamResolver
        }
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [TeamResolver]
})
```

From angular.io